# Is there a way to open RStudio with 32-bit R, but without changing the default from 64-bit?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to keep 64-bit R as the default when I open RStudio. But there are certain things that can only work with 32-bit R. When doing those tasks I'd like to toggle over to 32-bit R, but without changing the default settings in RStudio, which should continue to launch 64-bit R by default.